# Android Studio Crash. It opens for a few seconds and then closes

Tags: android, android-studio, crash

I open Android Studio, it runs for a few seconds and then it automatically closes. I have the latest version of jdk (14.0.1). I have also created the JDK_HOME system variable including the jdk path. When I open task manager, I can see the process still running.

[Android Studio after the launcher is completed and it is stuck like this for like 6-7 seconds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wz3Ch.png)

[Android Studio just before it closes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnC4D.png)

What do I have to do?

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu users, Just press CTR+H in FileManager (show hidden files). now you can see the .local file. now go to remove the google file from there. (Path -> local/share/google).

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by moving .android and AndroidStudioProjects from user folder to another folder. Then Android Studio opened and updated Android SDK. Afterwards it run normally.